# Obtendo dados de um nó que nao se sabe a referencia

Tags: firebase-database

Olá, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Para obtermos dados de determinado nó no Firebase especificamos o nó que o codigo usará de referencia, por exemplo:

A referencia será: "comida/frutas"

Com isso posso usar os métodos para obter o próprio valor "frutas" ou os filhos desse nó que poderia ser "laranja" usando o child ou até o filho de "laranja", que pode ser "laranja azeda" usando o método children. Até aqui tudo ok. mas e quando armazenamos os dados em um nó que foi inserido usando `push()`? com esse método o nó gerado terá um nome aleatório então como poderei inserir esse valor aleatório dentro de `.chil("nome aleatório gerado e que desconheço")`?

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui solucionar da maneira que queria mas resolvi usando o UUID gerado randomicamente e colocando o valor gerado como id daquilo que quero guardar no lugar de usar put para gerar um uuid aleatorio dentro do firbase.